# devextreme-datagrid update: message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"

Tags: angular, typescript, datagrid, devexpress, devextreme

***I'm having trouble updating the devextreme-datagrid.
 Could you help?***

***lineController.js***

```
 router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
      if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);
      console.log({
        msg: "Line guncelleme işlemi",
        gelenveri: req.body
      });
      var emp = {
        bant: req.body.bant,
        tarih: req.body.tarih,
        isKazasi: req.body.isKazasi,
        ramakKala: req.body.ramakKala,
        tamirAdedi: req.body.tamirAdedi,
        ikinciKaliteAdedi: req.body.ikinciKaliteAdedi,
        sevkiyattanGelenHata: req.body.sevkiyattanGelenHata,
        diger: req.body.diger,
        koliCikisAdedi: req.body.koliCikisAdedi,
        planlananAdet: req.body.planlananAdet,
        sam: req.body.sam,
        calisilanToplamSure: req.body.calisilanToplamSure,
        bantKisiSayisi: req.body.bantKisiSayisi,
        ilaveCalisilanDk: req.body.ilaveCalisilanDk,
        iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi: req.body.iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi,
        hataOrani:
          ((req.body.tamirAdedi +
            req.body.ikinciKaliteAdedi +
            req.body.sevkiyattanGelenHata +
            req.body.diger) /
            (req.body.koliCikisAdedi + req.body.ikinciKaliteAdedi)) *
          100,
        ikinciKaliteOrani:
          (req.body.ikinciKaliteAdedi /
            (req.body.koliCikisAdedi + req.body.ikinciKaliteAdedi)) *
          100,
        planlamayaUyum: (req.body.koliCikisAdedi / req.body.planlananAdet) * 100,
        hatVerimliligi:
          (req.body.koliCikisAdedi * req.body.sam) /
          (req.body.calisilanToplamSure * req.body.bantKisiSayisi),
        ilaveCalisma: (req.body.ilaveCalisilanDk * req.body.bantKisiSayisi) / 60,
        devamsizlikYuzdesi:
          (req.body.iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi / (req.body.bantKisiSayisi * 9)) * 100
      };
      Line.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: emp },
        { new: true },
        (err, doc) => {
          if (!err) {
            res.send(doc);
          } else {
            console.log(
              "satır güncelleme hatası:" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
            );
          }
        }
      );
    });
```

*line.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Line} from './line.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LineService {
  selectedLine: Line;
  lines: Line[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/lines';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  postLine(emp: Line) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, emp);
  }

  getLineList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

  // putLine(id, emp: Line) {
  //   return this.http.put(this.baseURL + `/${id}`, emp);
  // }
  putLine(emp: Line) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + `/${emp._id}`, emp);
  }

  deleteLine(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseURL + `/${_id}`);
  }
}
```

*line.component.html*

```
<dx-data-grid
          id="gridContainer"
          [dataSource]="lineService.lines"
          title="SQDCM Veri Gİrişi"
          keyExpr="_id"
          [columnAutoWidth]="true"
          [showBorders]="true"
          (onRowInserted)="onEdit($event)"
          (onRowUpdated)="onUpdate($event)"
          (onRowRemoved)="onDelete($event)"
        >
```

*line.component.ts*

```
onUpdate(event) {
  console.log(event);
  const merged = {_id: event.key, ...event.data};
   this.lineService.putLine(merged).subscribe(res => { });
}
```

*When I update the data, it writes it to the console.*

> {key: "5c6ac45adb48bf3850eebc74", data: {…}, component: inheritor,
>   element:
>   dx-data-grıd#gridContainer.dx-widget.dx-visibility-change-handler}
>   component: inheritor {_events: {…}, _eventsStrategy: NgEventsStrategy,
>   callBase: undefined, _$element: initRender(1), NAME: "dxDataGrid", …}
>   data: isKazasi: 8
>   **proto**: Object element: dx-data-grıd#gridContainer.dx-widget.dx-visibility-change-handler key:
>   "5c6ac45adb48bf3850eebc74"
>   **proto**: Object

*and gives an error:*

> { msg: 'Line guncelleme işlemi',   gelenveri: { _id:
>   '5c6ac45adb48bf3850eebc74', isKazasi: 8 } } satır güncelleme hatası:{ 
>   "message": "Cast to number failed for value \"NaN\" at path
>   \"devamsizlikYuzdesi\"",   "name": "CastError",   "stringValue":
>   "\"NaN\"",   "kind": "number",   "value": null,   "path":
>   "devamsizlikYuzdesi" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says there is an issue in the calculation of devamsizlikYuzdesi, the following line

```
devamsizlikYuzdesi:(req.body.iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi / (req.body.bantKisiSayisi * 9)) * 100
```

I think one / both of the following properties are / is undefined

`iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi` or `bantKisiSayisi.`

I belive checking those values for undefined and adding default value (0) to those properties should fix your problem.

Add the following before  var emp = {...

```
if(req.body.iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi == undefined){
    req.body.iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi = 0;
}

if(req.body.bantKisiSayisi == undefined){
    req.body.bantKisiSayisi = 0;
}
```

Comment: Both data are defined in both the database and the typescript field. could not find the error.

Comment: by undefined I meant their values are undefined / null

Comment: if I remove the calculation operations from the update function.?

Comment: you can simply test it by replacing (req.body.iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi / (req.body.bantKisiSayisi * 9)) * 100 with 0 (zero)

Comment: I'm new at programming. and I didn't understand you :(

Comment: Do you use the slack app?